# Is there any possibility to have access ask before saving data?

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, save

There's this program written by VBA running in Access. Every time we enter some data on a form and press the next record button on navigation bar data is saved automatically. I would like to know if there's a possibility to change this behavior, for example, to ask the user before saving the data.

Comment: Is the problem with updating existing records, or with inserting new records? The reason I ask is that the answer determines which events you use. Also, it may be that if it's an add record issue that you find it easier to use a separate unbound form for adding new records, instead of trying to control all the operations within a single form used for viewing, editing, adding and deleting.

Comment: sorry for the delay. I was not around for a while. It seems that it is actually a problem with updating data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible to use the before update event for the form with cancel and undo, but it is by no means infallible.

If there is some problem with data entry, do not think that asking will help, I have tried "Are you sure?" before, and the user gets into the habit of clicking yes automatically, followed by "oops".

Comment: Remou, yes, I'd agree with that behavior.  Far better to give them a means of being able to update things.